# Machine learning code works only when tested with training data but otherwise gives wrong answer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

First of all, thank you for going through my question. I am trying to develop a machine-learning model which will classify 3 distinct kinds of surface roughness (type 1, 2, and 3) when tested with image data. The training data is built using 5 sets of 2-D images (1024*768) and 3-D point cloud data for each roughness type. This means a total of 15 images and 15 point cloud is used to develop the training dataset. The below code works but gives the wrong answer when I try to test for a new image but work correctly when I test the code using images from the training data. Can someone please help?

```
  import numpy as np
    import os
    import cv2
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    
    data = []
    labels = []

# Loop through the three types of surface roughness types

    for i in range(1, 4):
        type_path = f"D:\\Ph.D. IEE\\Research\\My research\\Images\\type{i}"
    # Loop through the 5 images and point clouds for each type
for j in range(1, 6):
    # Read in the image and point cloud files
    image_path = os.path.join(type_path, f"{j}.png")
    point_cloud_path = os.path.join(type_path, f"{j}.csv")
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    point_cloud = np.loadtxt(point_cloud_path, delimiter='\t')
        # Append the image and point cloud to the data list
        data.append((image, point_cloud))
        # Append the label to the labels list
        labels.append(i)

# Convert the data and labels lists to NumPy arrays
data = np.array(data)
labels = np.array(labels)

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
train_data, test_data, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Reshape the training and testing data
train_images = train_data[:, 0]
train_images = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (1024, 768)) for img in train_images])
train_point_clouds = train_data[:, 1]
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)

test_images = test_data[:, 0]
test_images = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (1024, 768)) for img in test_images])
test_point_clouds = test_data[:, 1]
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

# Train a machine learning model on the training data
svm_model = SVC(kernel='linear')
svm_model.fit(train_images.reshape(-1, 1024*768*3), train_labels)

# Make a prediction on a testing image
test_image_path = "D:\\Ph.D. IEE\\Research\\My research\\Test\\t6.png"
test_image = cv2.imread(test_image_path)
test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, (1024, 768))
prediction = svm_model.predict(test_image.reshape(1, -1))[0]

# Map the prediction to the corresponding surface roughness type
if prediction == 1:
    print("The testing image falls under surface roughness type 1.")
elif prediction == 2:
    print("The testing image falls under surface roughness type 2.")
elif prediction == 3:
    print("The testing image falls under surface roughness type 3.")
else:
    print("The trained model could not predict the surface roughness. ")
```

Comment: Only 15 images? Are you kidding me? I guess you need a huge data augmentation. It's obvious that you ML model is overfitted with so few data.

Comment: So what do you suggest? How much data should I get per category? 100?

Comment: or better 1000. 100 is still a bit few.

Comment: 5 per type took an hour. This means I will need to spend 200 hours just collecting data?

Comment: " The below code works but gives the wrong answer when I try to test for a new image but work correctly when I test the code using images from the training data. " This is rather basic issue that you will encounter in statistical learning.

Comment: @Zlatan does that sound unreasonable to you? How do you think this all tends to work? So yeah, take more time or throw more computing resources at it are your options

Answer (score 4):

You're probably [overfitting](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/overfitting/). When you're overfitting, one thing that you can try is to simplify the model (i.e.: fewer layers, smaller layers). If that doesn't work, you may need more data, or you may need to [augment your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_augmentation).

[image]